# How do you color notes in Music21?

Tags: python, music21

How do you color code notes in visual displays with the [Music21](https://web.mit.edu/music21/) Python library?

I'm trying to create an animation where specific notes in sheet music are highlighted with a certain color at specific time intervals. So far I'm able to render sheet music with Music21 and code like:

```
import music21

music21.environment.set("musicxmlPath", "/usr/bin/musescore")
music21.environment.set("midiPath", "/usr/bin/timidity")

score = music21.converter.parse('score.abc')
score.show()
```

but it's only static and only black and white.

However, their documentation contains a [few examples](http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/moduleFiguredBassChecker.html#music21.figuredBass.checker.checkConsecutivePossibilities) of sheet music containing color coded notes. Yet I can't see how these images are generated. Much less how to do it dynamically.

Is this supported by the library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = note.Note('C#4')
n.style.color = 'red'
n.show()
```

On very old versions of music21 it'd be `n.color = 'red'; n.noteheadColor = 'red';` etc.